# Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) : How to enable HTTPS between Nginx Kubernetes Ingress Controller & Asp.Net Core 6.0 WebAPI PODs?

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-aks

I'm attempting to configure AKS, and I have the below setup

[image]

I want to enable HTTPS between Nginx Kubernetes Ingress Controller & Asp.Net Core 6.0 WebAPI PODs, like

[image]

How do I setup this? Where do I store the WebAPI SSL certificate?

Comment: Follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [documentation for annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol) to set the ingress backend to `HTTPS`:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
```

Follow the guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to setup SSL certs for your WebAPI pods.

The certs can be stored in kubernetes generic `secret` and can be mounted onto the pods as `volumes`. In production, the AKS secret storage could be [backed by Azure KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver), so the cert would be really stored in the KeyVault.

For your test environment, here is how you create secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic webapi-cert-secret 
  --from-file=cert=yourcert.pfx
  --from-literal=pass='yourcertpasswd'
```

Then mount into your pod/deployment definition (truncated for brevity):

```
      env:
      - name: Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path
        value: /certs/aspnet-cert.pfx
      - name: Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: webapi-cert-secret
            key: pass
      volumeMounts:
      - name: certsvolume
        mountPath: /certs/aspnet-cert.pfx
        subPath: aspnet-cert.pfx
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: certsvolume
    secret:
      secretName: webapi-cert-secret
      items:
      - key: cert
        path: aspnet-cert.pfx
```